# how to create different sequence of dates whose length equals to id length for each id?

Tags: sql, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sequence

I have a table with different length for each id and for which date_column value would be the same for each different id:

```
id     date_column
A      2020-05-20
A      2020-05-20
A      2020-05-20
B      2020-07-23    
B      2020-07-23
C      2021-08-27
C      2021-08-27
```

I would like to know if it possible to add an extra column generated
by a sequence of dates, where each start date value would be the unique date value for each id on date column, and subsequent values would be the start value less a month, the second value would be the start value less two months and so on, until a new id appears and a new start date value appears for which a new sequence would be generated.

Expected output should look like this -

```
id     date_column      generated_column    
A      2020-05-20        2020-05-20
A      2020-05-20        2020-04-20
A      2020-05-20        2020-03-20
B      2020-07-23        2020-07-23
B      2020-07-23        2020-06-23
C      2021-08-27        2021-08-27
C      2021-08-27        2021-07-27
```

Is it possible to add this column through the use of sql in snowflake?

Comment: Subtract the rownumber as month. From the date , as partition you can use I'd and the date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So just like nbk said, and Radagast note, but in slighty easier to read form (imho):

```
with fake_data(id, date_coumn) as (
    select * from values
        ('A', '2020-05-20'::date),
        ('A', '2020-05-20'::date),
        ('A', '2020-05-20'::date),
        ('B', '2020-07-23'::date),    
        ('B', '2020-07-23'::date),
        ('C', '2021-08-27'::date),
        ('C', '2021-08-27'::date)
)
select *
    ,row_number() over (partition by id order by null)-1 as rn
    ,dateadd('month', -rn, date_coumn) as gen_column
from fake_data
order by 1,gen_column desc;
```

gives:

[image]

which shows how the [row_number](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/row_number) is generating the values with seperate number ranges for each id, and how there is no value to sort these, but you can work around this by providing a constant value of which `null` works just great.
Then how the [dateadd](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/dateadd) is used to "add" negative months.

These two lines can be mashed together, as per Radagast's answer, but these can be hard to read/reason about, so another work-around which should equate to the same execution is to leave it in explicit form, and execlude the `rn` column via a sub-select like:

```
select * exclude(rn) from (
    select *
        ,row_number() over (partition by id order by null)-1 as rn
        ,dateadd('month', -rn, date_coumn) as gen_column
    from fake_data
)
order by 1,gen_column desc;
```

giving:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As @nbk eluded in the comment.....you can do

```
select *, add_months(date_column, -1 * (row_number() over (partition by id order by date_column)-1)
from t;
```